# howto size the width of a picture to the width of its webview

Tags: html, ios, image, uiwebview, size

I have a webview with a specific size :

```
    let webviewwidth:CGFloat=self.view.frame.width * 0.85;
    let webviewheigth:CGFloat=(self.view.frame.height - navbarHeigth) * 0.85;

    myWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, navbarHeigth , webviewwidth, webviewheigth));
```

with the content of:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" width=????? alt="" border=0><br>
```

How can I set the size an image (?????) to the size of its webview ?
When setting the width in HTML to the webviewsize, it will be to large, because the width of the webview is in points and not pixels.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the css I use for img in webview

```
img {max-width: 100%;height: auto;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
```

If you want every img width to be 100% just replace `max-width` to `width`